# How do I get the shard name?

Tags: mongodb, sharding, zone

I have created three shards. I want to add them to zones. But the API for adding to zones :

```
sh.addShardToZone(shard, zone)
```

Requires a shard name. Now while defining config for the shards, I did not assign any name. I just specified the IP. Below is the extract from the sh.status command.

```
 shards:
        {  "_id" : "ShardReplSet",  "host" : "ShardReplSet/localhost:27021,localhost:27022,localhost:27023",  "state" : 1 }
```

What should I pass as shard name for adding shard to a zone?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/sh.status/ shard name is the same as its _id (`ShardReplSet` in your output).